# Joining tables to get count in api request

Tags: sql, join

I want to create an sql query for following scenario.

I've 3 tables `request`, `contract_template` and `contract_type`. 
`Request` table has `contract_template_id` as foreign key, `contract_template` has `contract_type_id` as foreign key. I want to get count of each contract type based on the records in request table.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$data['contractStatus'] = DB::table('request') -> join('configuration', 'request.contract_status_id', '=', 'configuration.id') ->join('contract_template', 'request.contract_template_id', '=', 'contract_template.id') ->join('contract_type', 'contract_template.contract_type_id', '=', 'contract_type.id') ->select('contract_type.name', 'configuration.value')->groupBy('contract_type.name', 'configuration.value')->get();
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and what your exact problems are.

Comment: $data['contractStatus'] = DB::table('request')
            ->join('configuration', 'request.contract_status_id', '=', 'configuration.id')
            ->join('contract_template', 'request.contract_template_id', '=', 'contract_template.id')
            ->join('contract_type', 'contract_template.contract_type_id', '=', 'contract_type.id')
            ->select('contract_type.name', 'configuration.value')->groupBy('contract_type.name', 'configuration.value')->get();

Comment: Above is the laravel code i've written so far to join records but i'm not getting the expected output. Actually i want to fetch data from database and display a contractType vs contractStatus graph.

Comment: @Manish What did u get as a response?

Comment: @Manish do you want a sql query or laraval code for sql query?

Comment: I want an sql query. i will build the laravel code based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are expecting, as far as I understand your question you wanted a sql query. Check the below query.

```
select contract_type.name,count(contract_type.name) from request 
inner join contract_template  on request.contract_template_id =contract_template.contract_template_id 
inner join contract_type  on contract_template.contract_type_id =contract_type.contract_type_id
group by contract_type.name
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.Solved